# Check whether input taken by a int datatype is valid

Tags: c++, validation

I have an integer variable named `i`.

When reading from `cin`:

```
cin >> i;
```

How can I confirm that the user input is a valid integer, and not just any character?

Comment: You may want to have a look on this function [isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)

Comment: You can check for both valid input *and* stream validation by `if (cin >> i)...` last I checked. Failure to do a proper extract should set the streams failbit, You need something more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the last (set of) input succeeded with

```
if (cin) { /* still good */ }
```

or

```
if (cin.good()) { /* still good */ }
```

You can also get the input and check the success in one go:

```
if (cin >> i) { /* still good */ }
```

All of these methods have one drawback, and that is that the offending input will not be removed from `cin` and there is no way to tell mow much there is.

A more robust way of getting user input and validating it is to first read a line of input into a string and then extract the information from that string. For example:

```
string line;
int i;
if (getline(cin, line))
{
  stringstream ss(line);
  if (ss >> i)
  {
    /* we have got our int */
  }
  else
  {
    /* That was not an integer entered by the user */
  }
}
else
{
  /* The user did not enter anything */
}
```